# sorting an arrray with 2-3 nests javascript/lodash

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting, underscore.js, lodash

Unable to understand how to sort this kind of data which has array inside nested array...

```
var data = {
   d1: [{
      nest1: {a:5, b:2},
      nest2: {a:3, b:1},
   }],
   d3: [{
      nest1: {a:7, b:9},
      nest2: {a:1, b:22},
   }],
   d2: [{
      nest1: {a:1, b:9},
      nest2: {a:11, b:22},
   }],
}
```

so basically, want to sort by a, b, key.

So First of all, I have iterated all objects to get an array(to be able to sort by key)

Now data looks like (just example)

```
data = [{
   key: "d1",
   obj: [{
      nest1: {a:1, b:2},
      nest2: {a:3, b:12},
   }]}],
  [{
   key: "d2",
   obj: [{
      nest1: {a:11, b:12},
      nest2: {a:13, b:22},
   }]}]
```

so now I can sort by key easily -

```
_.orderBy(vm.summaryData, 'key')
```

but still confused, how to sort by data.obj.nest1.a ??

Expectation: sort by key itself:

```
data = {
   d1: [{
      nest1: {a:5, b:2},
      nest2: {a:3, b:1},
   }],
   d2: [{
      nest1: {a:1, b:9},
      nest2: {a:11, b:22},
   }],
   d3: [{
      nest1: {a:7, b:9},
      nest2: {a:1, b:22},
   }],
}
```

Expectation: sort by nest1.a:

```
data = {
   d2: [{
      nest1: {a:1, b:9},
      nest2: {a:11, b:22},
   }],
   d1: [{
      nest1: {a:5, b:2},
      nest2: {a:3, b:1},
   }],
   d3: [{
      nest1: {a:7, b:9},
      nest2: {a:1, b:22},
   }],
}
```

Expectation: sort by nest2.a:

```
data = {
   d3: [{
      nest1: {a:7, b:9},
      nest2: {a:1, b:22},
   }],
   d1: [{
      nest1: {a:5, b:2},
      nest2: {a:3, b:1},
   }],
   d2: [{
      nest1: {a:1, b:9},
      nest2: {a:11, b:22},
   }],
}
```

and so on...nest1.b, nest2.b.....

Comment: what is meant by sorting in this case? please add some more examples or a greater one.

Comment: Ok, but have already given the example/case.

Comment: Data is not a valid javascript object

Comment: sorry for typo, corrected it.

Comment: Thanks Nina, added expected results as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could take the path to the property for sorting with a string, separated by dots for sorting.

```js
function convert(object) {
    return Object
        .keys(object)
        .map(function (key) {
            return { key: key, obj: object[key] };
        });
}

var data = { d1: { nest1: { a: 1, b: 2 }, nest2: { a: 3, b: 12 } }, d2: { nest1: { a: 11, b: 1 }, nest2: { a: 13, b: 22 } } },
    result = convert(data);

console.log(_.orderBy(result, 'obj.nest1.b'));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.15.0/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

JavaScript objects are not ordered. It is meaningless to try to "sort" them. But if you create a new object with sorted keys, it will work.

```js
var data = {d1: [{nest1: {a:5, b:2},nest2: {a:3, b:1},}],d3: [{nest1: {a:7, b:9},nest2: {a:1, b:22},}],d2: [{nest1: {a:1, b:9},nest2: {a:11, b:22},}],};

let sortData = (data, path) => {
  let sortedKey = !path ? Object.keys(data).sort() :
                 Object.keys(data).sort((ka,kb) => {
                 let key1 = path.split('.').reduce((o,i) => o[i],data[ka][0]),
                     key2 = path.split('.').reduce((o,i) => o[i],data[kb][0]);
                 return key1 - key2; 
                });

   return sortedKey.reduce((r,k) => { r[k] = data[k]; return r; },{})
}

console.log(sortData(data));
console.log(sortData(data,'nest1.a'));
console.log(sortData(data,'nest2.a'));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```